# All queries are slow with neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I have written a variety of queries using cypher that take no less than 200ms per query. They're very straightforward, so I'm having trouble identifying where the bottleneck is.

**Simple Match with Parameters, 2200ms:**

[image: SimpleMatchWithParameters]

**Simple Distinct Match with Parameters, 200ms:**

[image: SimpleDistinctMatchWithParameters]

**Pathing, 2500ms:**

[image]

At first I thought the issue was a lack of resources, because I was running neo4j and my application on the same box. While the performance monitor indicated that CPU and memory were largely free'd up and available, I moved the neo4j server to another local box and observed similar latency. Both servers are workstations with fairly new Xeon processors, 12GB memory and SSDs for the data storage. All of the above leads me to believe that the latency isn't due to my hardware. OS is Windows 7.

The graph has less than 200 nodes and less than 200 relationships.

I've attached some queries that I send to neo4j along with the configuration for the server, database, and JVM. No plugins or extensions are loaded.

Pastebin Links:

- [Database Configuration](http://pastebin.com/6u7VpkeY)
- [Server Configuration](http://pastebin.com/HiMkMM1Q)
- [JVM Configuration](http://pastebin.com/gJknp6CY)

Comment: Tim can you share your graph.db/messages.log eg. in pastebin? Something really seems to be off with your setup although the config looks good. Could also be an windows issue, do you have any means on running this on MacOS or Linux (e.g. AWS) for a comparison?

Comment: The entire log was too big for pastebin, but I've copied the past few days to this paste: http://pastebin.com/SLNVHDbK

Comment: Tim, could you test setting the database config manually to some fixed values, for your small store just uncommenting the values starting with `#neostore.` (i.e. remove the #) should work fine. It could be that having loads of RAM on the machine causes neo to allocate too much for memory mapping eating into your heap (on windows memory mapping is also done on the heap).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Expanding a bit on a comment I made earlier.]

@TFerrell: Your comments state that "all nodes have labels", and that you tried applying indexes. However, it is not clear if you actually specified the labels in your *slow Cypher queries*. I noticed from your original question statement that neither of your slower queries actually specified a node label (which presumably should have been "Project").

If your Cypher query does not specify the label for a node, then the DB engine has to test every node, and it also cannot apply an index.

So, please try specifying the correct node label(s) in your slow queries.

Comment: Ultimately, this was the resolution. Modifying the queries to use the applied labels resulted in queries running less than 10ms in all cases. However, Michael Hunger's assistance in providing the code for the Entity label does allow me a common interface for efficiently querying all nodes.

Answer (score 4):

Is that the first run or a subsequent run of these queries?

You probably don't have a label on your nodes and no index or unique constraint.

So Neo4j has to scan the whole store for your node pulling everything into memory, loading the properties and checking.

try this:

run until count returns 0:

```
match (n) where not n:Entity set n:Entity return count(*);
```

add the constraint

```
create constraint on (e:Entity) assert e.Id is unique;
```

run your query again:

```
match (n:Element {Id:{Id}}) return n
```

etc.

Comment: All runs, first or consequent are slow. All nodes also have labels, but there is no index or unique constraint. That being said, 200ms to scan <200 nodes and return 1 seems excessive. I'm having trouble believing I'd need indexes for that small of a set.

Comment: I ran the constraint queries as you suggested, but am still experiencing high query times. I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: As Michael suggested, try putting indexes on your nodes for the property you are searching for and run your time tests then.

Comment: @Nicholas - I did apply the indexes but observed no difference in execution speed.

Comment: Have you configured any of the caching options? The penalty should be heavy on the first query, but better on subsequent queries if you have the caching enabled.

Comment: I applied the cache as well, still no change. Updated neo4j.properties can be found here: http://pastebin.com/qNCREDmM  Also, JVM heap size was upgraded to 3g.

Comment: @TFerrell: You said "all nodes have labels", and that you applied indexes. However, it is not clear if you actually specified the labels in your slow Cypher *queries*. I noticed from your original query that neither of your slower queries actually specified a node label (presumably, "Project"). Please try specifying the correct label in your slow queries.

Answer (score 2):

It seems there is something wrong with the automatic memory mapping calculation when you are on Windows (memory mapping on heap).

I just looked at your `messages.log` and added up some numbers, so it seems the mmio alone is enough to fill your java heap space (old-gen) leaving no room for the database, caches etc.

Please try to amend that by fixing the mmio config in your `conf/neo4j.properties` to more sensible values (than the auto-calculation). 
For your small store just uncommenting the values starting with #neostore. (i.e. remove the #) should work fine.

Otherwise something like this (fitting for a 3GB heap) for a larger graph (2M nodes, 10M rels, 20M props,10M long strings):

```
 neostore.nodestore.db.mapped_memory=25M
 neostore.relationshipstore.db.mapped_memory=250M
 neostore.propertystore.db.mapped_memory=250M
 neostore.propertystore.db.strings.mapped_memory=250M
 neostore.propertystore.db.arrays.mapped_memory=0M
```

Here are the added numbers:

```
auto mmio: 134217728 + 134217728 + 536870912 + 536870912 + 1073741824 = 2.3GB
stores sizes: 1073920 + 1073664 + 3221698 + 3221460 + 1073786 = 9MB

JVM max: 3.11 RAM : 13.98 SWAP: 27.97 GB
max heaps: Eden: 1.16, oldgen: 2.33
```

taken from:

```
neostore.propertystore.db.strings] brickCount=8 brickSize=134144b mappedMem=134217728b (storeSize=1073920b)
neostore.propertystore.db.arrays] brickCount=8 brickSize=134144b mappedMem=134217728b (storeSize=1073664b)
neostore.propertystore.db] brickCount=6 brickSize=536854b mappedMem=536870912b (storeSize=3221698b)
neostore.relationshipstore.db] brickCount=6 brickSize=536844b mappedMem=536870912b (storeSize=3221460b)
neostore.nodestore.db] brickCount=1 brickSize=1073730b mappedMem=1073741824b (storeSize=1073786b)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't make any difference to the query times. I'll try to load an Linux VM and see if it's OS related.