# Neo4j slow matching and traversing, even with indexes

Tags: neo4j

I have a graph of ~49M nodes and ~37M relationships (~7GB), and am running the following query:

```
MATCH (n:NAME {name: "dummy name"})-[:ID*1..2]-(similar_names:NAME {type:"name"}) RETURN DISTINCT(similar_names)
```

where the query is meant to start off from a node which has the specific name attribute "dummy name" (which is unique), and get all the "NAME"-labeled nodes with a type attribute value of "name", as long as these are connected by an edge of type ID. This query works well in terms of results, but takes over 850 ms. Although this is not initially an issue, this is only with a depth of up to 2, and my aim is for infinite traversal depth. With -[:ID*], the query does not complete (within 5 mins).

I have indexed the attributes for the labels used in this query (which should address answers to other SO questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358291/all-queries-are-slow-with-neo4j). Querying has been performed through neo4j desktop browser and I have configured 10GB of memory to 'make sure' memory configuration is not the bottleneck.

Any ideas on how this can be further optimized? Or what I may be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matching and traversal in cypher is optimized for finding all possible paths that meet a matched pattern. Unfortunately this isn't the best approach when all you want is distinct nodes at the end of the path, and don't care about the paths used to find those end nodes.

APOC Procedures has [path finding procs](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_expand_paths) that are optimized for this case, specifically `apoc.path.subgraphNodes()`.

Here's how you would use this:

```
MATCH (n:NAME {name: "dummy name"})
CALL apoc.path.subgraphNodes(n, {maxLevel:2, relationshipFilter:'ID'}) YIELD node as similar_name
WITH similar_name
WHERE similar_name.type = 'name' AND n <> similar_name
RETURN similar_name
```

You can try this increasing the maxLevel, and removing maxLevel when you feel it can work at an unlimited depth.

Comment: What do you mean by "meet a matched pattern" exactly? Given the relationship type is specified, I would think even my query has a pattern? Or do you mean directionality defined? With this approach (subgraphNodes) can you filter the relationships also by an attribute?

Comment: Your query certainly has a pattern to be matched. My comment was to emphasize Cypher traverses all possible paths, no matter how many of them lead to the same end node. That's a lot of extra work that you probably don't care about, if you're after distinct end nodes. `subgraphNodes()` can't filter based on relationship properties, you wouldn't be able to use this approach if you need that.